# How Can python create tuple of tuple with time elements?

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, python-datetime

I wanna create a tuple like this:

```
(('0', '00:00:00'), ('1', '00:30:00'), ('2', '00:01:00') ..., ('46', '23:00:00'), ('47', '23:30:00'))
```

Attempts:

```
lines = []
a = datetime.timedelta(minutes=0)
for ii in range (48):
    lines.append(a)
    a = a.timedelta(minutes=30)
```

I tried various ways, but I don't know really what should I do?

Comment: Post your attempts..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feels like something that can be done with [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) and [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) objects.

For the tuple creation tuple I've used a generator expression.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> dt = datetime(1970 ,1 ,1)
>>> t = timedelta(minutes=30)
>>> tuple((str(i), (dt + (i * t)).strftime("%X")) for i in range(48))
(('0', '00:00:00'), ..., ('47', '23:30:00'))
>>>
```

Comment: I've missed your answer : ) Thanks for warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize a [generator](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html#generators) to build a list of times at 30 minute intervals.

```
def yield_times():  
    start = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(0, 0))
    yield start.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    while True:
        start += timedelta(minutes=30)
        yield start.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

---

Using this generator, we can create a list of tuples. `48` in this case, is the number of iterations through the generator. This `range` statement will start at `0`, giving us values 0 - 47.

```
gen = yield_times()
tuple_list = []
for ii in range(48):
    tuple_list.append((ii, gen.next()))
```

---

Finally, we need to convert the list of tuples to a tuple of tuples:

```
tuple_times = tuple(tuple_list)
```

---

Full script:

```
from datetime import date, time, datetime, timedelta
def yield_times():  
    start = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(0, 0))
    yield start.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    while True:
        start += timedelta(minutes=30)
        yield start.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

gen = yield_times()
tuple_list = []
for ii in range(48):
    tuple_list.append((ii, gen.next()))

tuple_times = tuple(tuple_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, but `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 12, in <module>
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'`

Answer (score 0):

Try use list with tuple convertion

```
l = []
for i in xrange(10):
    l.append(('1', '00:30:00'))   <--- set your data here
t  =tuple(l)   # convert it to tuple
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I add to the time 30 minutes each time?

Comment: use datetime.timedelta function for creating and strptime to string convertion